# В ожидании получения данных

Tags: c#

Есть у модели метод авторизации

В нём ввод логина, ввод пароля и ещё ввод кода из смс

Вот по среди выполненеия метода, нужно получить код смс от пользователя.

Я обычно все ожидания делал тупо через `while` - опрашивая свойство c определённой задержкой

```
public string SmsCode { get; set;}

while(SmsCode == null)
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
}
```

А как можно ещё поступить более правильно ?

Comment: Что это? Сайт? Десктоп приложение? Что? Судя по вашим старым вопросам, это MAIU Android... То есть, приложение, которым в данный момент пользуется только один пользователь. Тогда вопрос... Зачем ожидать? Сохранили нужные данные где-то в локальных полях, отправили окно для ввода SMS, все. Как только человек кликнет на кнопку отправки кода, по команде дополняете сохраненные данные и отправляете куда надо для проверки. Не, можете конечно и ждать, без проблем, да и бесконечные циклы это вполне адекватный инструмент (только токен отмены не забывайте), но как по мне, ожидание тут лишнее.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ про сохранить где то не подумал чтобы потом дополнить))) спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через колбэк и `TaskCompletionSource`.

```
private TaskCompletionSource _tcs;

private void OnSmsCodeReceived()
{
    if (_tcs is null)
        return;

    _tcs.SetResult();
    _tcs = null;
}

private Task WaitForSmsCodeAsync()
{
    if (_tcs is null)
        _tcs = new();
       
    return _tcs.Task;
}
```

Свойство получится такое

```
private string _smsCode;

public string SmsCode
{
    get => _smsCode;
    set
    {
        _smsCode = value;
        if (value is not null)
            OnSmsCodeReceived();
    }
}
```

А ожидание такое

```
await WaitForSmsCodeAsync();
```

Единственное, что здесь может пойти теоретически не так, это если код придёт раньше, чем вы начали ожидание. Но подозреваю, что это в реальной жизни невозможно.

Идея, я думаю, ясна. Но вероятно можно завернуть подобным образом методы запроса кода. Чтобы сама операция асинхронно возвращала код, а не свойство мониторить. Хотя, с помощью `TaskCompletionSource` можно что угодно превратить в ожидаемое через `await`.

Comment: спасибо большое за развёрнутый ответ!!!